# binary bomb content of register added

Tags: assembly, binary

I'm working on a binary bomb which take more than three argument, here's a portion of the bomb that I don't understand:

```
0x08048db2 <+0>:    sub    $0x3c,%esp
0x08048db5 <+3>:    lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax
0x08048db9 <+7>:    mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
0x08048dbd <+11>:   lea    0x27(%esp),%eax
0x08048dc1 <+15>:   mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x08048dc5 <+19>:   lea    0x28(%esp),%eax
0x08048dc9 <+23>:   mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x08048dcd <+27>:   movl   $0x804a56d,0x4(%esp)
0x08048dd5 <+35>:   mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
0x08048dd9 <+39>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048ddc <+42>:   call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x08048de1 <+47>:   cmp    $0x2,%eax
0x08048de4 <+50>:   jg     0x8048deb <phase_5+57>
0x08048de6 <+52>:   call   0x8049535 <explode_bomb>
```

the bomb later compare the content of 0x27(%esp) with a number. But at 0x08048ddc <+42>, the content of 0x27(%esp) is updated and I can't figure out how did it do that even after I look into the function.
if my input is "1 -997 1 2 301", the content of 0x27(%esp) would be 301
if my input is "0 7 817 8 9", the content of 0x27(%esp) would be 55

The bomb also updated the content of 0x2c(%esp) with <__isoc99_sscanf@plt> function. I can't figure out what the content of 0x2c(%esp) is from.
Thank you!

Comment: __isoc99_sscanf@plt is actually a trampoline to the C sscanf function; it is extracting data from a string. To understand how it is interpreting it, you have to at least find out what the format string is; my bet, even without reading the code carefully, is on that $0x804a56d, which has the taste of a string literal.

Comment: Hi, Thank you and the format is "%d %c %d"

Comment: so it take a integer, character and anotehr integer?

Comment: It takes the address to the source string, the address to the format string and then *the address* to an integer, *the address* to a character and *the address* to another integer.

Comment: Thank you! I defused the bomb!

Comment: how did you know the string literal is on $0x804a56d tho?

Comment: In facts, the relevant addresses are computed by those `lea`, and are put in their place on the stack by the `mov` that follow.

Comment: Because it was the only hard-coded number in the code which was big enough to be a believable address, so it was either a pointer to some static data (as it was), or a pointer to a global buffer written by someone else; still, when writing C code, your format string is normally a string literal, which gets written as-is in the rodata section of the executable and whose pointer gets written straight in the code, as happens here. Also, it was put in the right place (esp+4) before the call to sscanf.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation made this code so easy to me now!